# Problemas al llamar dos ventanas PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Buenas y gracias por leer mi pregunta. Mi aplicación consiste en una venta con dos botones, al dar clic en cualquier botón llamara una Qwidget de un archivo py (dos botones dos archivos py, haré referencia como archivo 1 y archivo 2). Los problemas que actualmente tengo es que al ejecutar la aplicación (archivo main), de inicio abre la ventana del archivo 1, al cerrar abre la ventana del archivo 2, y al cerrar esta, como ultimo ejecuta la aplicación de main. Ese es el primer problema, el segundo es que al cerrar la aplicación de main en consola me aparece: "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)".

Mi solicitud es si pueden indicarme como hacer para que no abra las ventanas de los archivos py 1 y 2, solamente lo hagan cuando yo le de clic a sus respectivos botones en la aplicación de main y que podria ser ese error en consola.

Gracias. Dejo codigos.

archivo main py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QFormLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit, QMessageBox, QSpinBox

import sys

from programacion import Window
from Trimestre import Window2

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Programación", self)
        self.btn1.move (10,10)
        self.btn1.resize(150, 40)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked1)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Seguimiento", self)
        self.btn2.move(200, 10)
        self.btn2.resize(150, 40)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked2)

        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setMaximumSize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('CONALEP Programa Operativo Anual (POA)')
        self.show()

        self.accion1 = Window()
        self.accion2 = Window2()

        self.buttonClicked1()
        self.buttonClicked2()


    def buttonClicked1(self):
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.accion1.show)

    def buttonClicked2(self):
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.accion2.show)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Archivo 1 py "programacion"

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Programación Programa Operativo Anual')

app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Archivo 2 py "Trimestre"

```
class Window2(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Seguimiento Trimestra Programa Operativo Anual')


app = QApplication([])
w = Window2()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: 1) no entiendo como te funcionan los módulos sin declarar el uso de pyqt 2)todo lo que está después del atributo setWindowTitle, fuera de la clase está demás, si lo usas como módulo, aunque también podrías dejarlo si usas como en el archivo main if __name__ etc

Comment: Amigo tu comentario me ayudo, pero trata de ser mas amable, si están las preguntas acá es por total desconocimiento. Soy nuevo, gracias por tu respuesta. No se como calificarte no me aparece la opción.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al comentario de tincopasan, en los archivos 1 y 2 que se llaman al dar clic en su respectivo botón se debe de borrar:

```
app = QApplication([])
w = Window2()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Lo anterior hace que la aplicación entre en un bucle de tratar de ejecutar todos los archivos.